# Where to find Dummy Data For Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, data

I don't know if the question is relevant, but if someone can give me some info, I'll be very grateful. I have found this [website](https://www.generatedata.com/)
- here for generating dummy data. I have found some .dump files full of data (unfortunately they are paid to download), but I can't find some dummy data for learning purposes for Oracle. I just need a bigger table from 10k to 100k records, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can install Oracle products or have access to the scripts on database server side you can try to install the examples: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/EXMPL/toc.htm#CEGCAGJH.

You can also adapt following code to your needs:

```
SQL> create table t(id number primary key, c1 varchar2(20), c2 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  select rownum, 'first' || rownum, 'last' ||  rownum
  3  from dual
  4  connect by
  5  level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from t order by id;

    ID C1           C2
---------- -------------------- --------------------
     1 first1       last1
     2 first2       last2
     3 first3       last3
     4 first4       last4
     5 first5       last5
     6 first6       last6
     7 first7       last7
     8 first8       last8
     9 first9       last9
    10 first10      last10

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Yes, this is one solution that can actually work. I have installed oracle's free schemas, however there aren't many dummy records in them. I also just found several .dump files with about 5000 records, which are free and usable!

Answer (score 0):

For learning purposes, I assume that you have installed oracle on your personal computer. If that is the case, oracle installation comes with default schemas that you can choose to install during installation. If you skipped this part during installation, you still can install the default schemas since the scripts are saved.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC109) is a guideline on how you can install the default schemas